# ¿Este tipo de expresiones siempre permanece en memoria?

Tags: c#, .net

Trasteando con C# me he topado con que se puede crear una nueva instancia sin almacenarla dentro de algún identificador.

Entiendo que dichas declaraciones solo funcionan con clases por la necesidad de invocar algún método dentro de estas, pero ¿Esta instancia permanece siempre en memoria?

Ejemplo, supongamos que tengo la siguiente clase:

```
class Printer
{
    private string _internal;
    public void Print() { Console.WriteLine(_internal); }
    public Printer(string s) { _internal = s; }
}
```

Y llamo desde:

```
static void Main()
{
    new Printer("Hola Mundo!").Print(); // Imprime "Hola Mundo"
}
```

El objeto de tipo `Printer` que fué instanciado permanecerá siempre en memoria hasta finalizar la ejecución del programa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Las instancias de los objetos tienen un scope en el cual son accesibles, en este caso la instancia del `Printer` es el metodo Main() cuando salgas del mismo la instancia queda disponible para ser recolectada por el [Garbage Collector](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/daniem/2009/07/09/cosas-que-deberas-saber-sobre-el-garbage-collector-de-net/) (GC)

Si quieres asegurar una destruccion efectiva del objeto usa el bloque `using`

```
static void Main()
{
    using(Printer printer = new Printer("Hola Mundo!"))
    {
        printer.Print();
    }
}
```

Las variables tienen un ambito en el cual pueden usarse, cuando sales del mismo el GC las puede recolectar y liberar la memoria, pero esto es automatico para ti.

Comment: Deberías aclarar que para utilizar `using` la clase que se construya debe implementar `IDisposable`

Answer (score 0):

Sí, el objeto de tipo **Printer** instanciado va permanecer siempre en memoria y será eliminado de la misma cuando se invoque al destructor de **Printer**, generalmente cuando termina la ejecución del programa.

Creo que una clase estática sería buena para tu implementación ;)

Comment: Lo sé, pero me ví en el caso de usar una libreria que no es mía _(sin codigo fuente)_ donde sólo necesitaba un método, más no un objeto.

Comment: Esta respuesta es incorrecta, la instancia permanecerá en memoria hasta que el Garbage Collector automáticamente reclame la memoria que ya no está accesible. En el ejemplo trivial que el NaCl probablemente de lo mismo pero en el caso general no.

Comment: No es del todo incorrecta, pues, acabo de probar algo parecido, pero al proyecto en el que si tuve que aplicar la declaración, le afectó un poco.